# Wordpress Custom Post Type: Pagination reloads same content on every page

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type

So I have a custom post type called `broadcast` and it is currently spitting out 10 posts a page onto an archive page. However, when you switch pages via pagination, the URL changes to `page/2/` and the current button at the bottom changes, but the same 10 posts remain the same. So the pagination side of things seems to be working, it just isn't loading in different posts. Here's the code (this might be too much, but better to have more context than less):

```
<?php
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('broadcast'),
    'post_status' => array('publish'),
    'nopaging' => false,
    'offset' => 1,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'paged' => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'format',
            'terms' => 'videos',
            'field' => 'slug'
        )
    )
);

// The Query
$broadcasts = new WP_Query($args);

// The Loop
if ($broadcasts->have_posts()) {
    while ($broadcasts->have_posts()) {
        $broadcasts->the_post(); ?>

        // SHOW THE POSTS HERE

    <?php } ?>

    <!-- Start Pagination-->
    <div class="col-span-12 p-5 mb-8 pagination text-center">
        <?php

        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base' => str_replace(999999999, '%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link(999999999))),
            'total' => $broadcasts->max_num_pages,
            'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
            'format' => '?paged=%#%',
            'show_all' => false,
            'type' => 'list',
            'end_size' => 2,
            'mid_size' => 1,
            'prev_next' => true,
            'prev_text' => sprintf('<i></i> %1$s', __('Newer Videos', 'text-domain')),
            'next_text' => sprintf('%1$s <i></i>', __('Older Videos', 'text-domain')),
            'add_args' => false,
            'add_fragment' => '',
        ));
        ?>
    </div>

    <?php
} else {
    echo 'there are no posts.'; // no posts found
}
// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Any help is appreciated, I've gotten nowhere reading docs, as this * should * work and it isn't throwing errors for me to debug.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of your issue is offset parameter.

When offset parameter is set, paged parameter will be ignored.

Check WP_Query parameters.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-page-parameters

> offset (int) – number of post to displace or pass over. Warning: Setting the offset parameter overrides/ignores the paged parameter and breaks pagination. The 'offset' parameter is ignored when 'posts_per_page'=>-1 (show all posts) is used.

I think you are trying to skip the latest post.

In this case you can use the following code.

```
$latest_post_args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'broadcast',
    'numberposts'   => 1,
    'fields'        => 'ids',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'format',
            'terms' => 'videos',
            'field' => 'slug'
        )
    )
);

$latest_post_ids = get_posts( $latest_post_args );

$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('broadcast'),
    'post_status' => array('publish'),
    'nopaging' => false,
    'post__not_in' => $latest_post_ids,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'paged' => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'format',
            'terms' => 'videos',
            'field' => 'slug'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Perfect. I was in fact trying to skip the most recent post (because it didn't make sense that I showed the "latest video" and then it was immediately under that in "all videos."). 

I tried deleting the code that gets the latest one in hopes that would fix it, but I never thought to check to see if the issue was with the offset. Thank you so much!