# Woocommerce - Pagination links reload same page content in a custom template

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to build my own custom downloads.php template. Everything works fine except pagination. The error occurs when clicking on any page number, for example; if you click on page 2 the link changes from mywebsite.com/account/downloads to mywebsite.com/account/downloads/2 but the content of the page is the same as the first page.

I've been looking around for my own problem but can't find a solution that works for me:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops

[Wordpress Custom Post Type: Pagination reloads same content on every page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71873725/wordpress-custom-post-type-pagination-reloads-same-content-on-every-page)

There are other similar questions without an accepted answer, but they all agree that you have to define your own query for paged variable.

Can anyone clarify this? I would be very grateful, I appreciate any help, thank you.

Update: I fixed some errors I was getting on the display when wp_debug is true. Now I no longer have any errors but the problem of the carimaneto of the same page remains.

**My custom template**

```
<?php

?><div class="orders-container"><?php


defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

// Variable for Array $args ($customer_orders)
$order_statuses = array('wc-completed');
$current_page = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

//Custom Query
$args = array(
    'customer_id' => get_current_user_id(),
    'post_status'     => $order_statuses,
    'paged'           => $current_page,
    'posts_per_page'  => 8,
    'paginate'        => true,
);
$customer_orders = wc_get_orders( $args );

// Start if Condition
if ( $customer_orders ) {
                
 ?><table class="table_orders heading"><tr>
  <td class="product_number">Ordine</td>
  <td class="product_name">Prodotto</td>
  <td class="product_data">Data</td>
  <td class="product_price">Totale</td>
  <td class="product_status">Stato</td>
  <td class="product_action">File</td>
 </tr></table><?php

    foreach($customer_orders->orders as $order){
        $orders_id = $order->get_id();
        $date_created = $order->get_date_created()->date('d/m/Y');
        $order_total = $order->get_formatted_order_total();
        $status =  wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() );
        $view_order = $order->get_view_order_url();

        foreach($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item){
            $product_name = $item->get_name();

            echo '
                <table class="table_orders">
                <tr class="table_row_items">
                    <td class="product_number">
                     <span class="mobile title">Ordine</span>
                     <span>#'. esc_attr($orders_id) .'</span>
                    </td>
    
                    <td class="product_name">
                     <span class="mobile title">Prodotto</span>
                     <a href="'. wp_kses_post($view_order) .'">'. wp_kses_post($product_name) .'</a>
                    </td>
    
                    <td class="product_data">
                     <span class="mobile title">Data</span>
                     <span>'. wp_kses_post($date_created) .'</span>
                    </td>
    
                    <td class="product_price">
                     <span class="mobile title">Prezzo</span>
                     <span>'. wp_kses_post($order_total) .'</span>
                    </td>
    
                    <td class="product_status">
                     <span class="mobile title">Stato</span>
                     <span class="label ' . $order->get_status() . '">'. wp_kses_post($status) .'</span>
                    </td>
 
                    <td class="product_action">
                     <span class="mobile title">File</span>
                     <a target=”_blank” href="'. esc_url($view_order) .'">Visualizza<i class="fa-duotone fa-eye"></i></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>    
                </table> 
            ';
        }   
    }

    // Pagination button - Responsabile dei bottoni e numerazione delle pagine della cronologia ordini
    ?><div class="container-pagination"><?php 
        $args = array(
         'base'          => esc_url( wc_get_endpoint_url( 'my-endpoint' ) ) . '%_%', //Here I put my custom endpoint
         'format'        => '%#%',
         'total'         => $customer_orders->max_num_pages,
         'current'       => $current_page,
         'show_all'      => false,
         'end_size'      => 3,
         'mid_size'      => 3,
         'prev_next'     => true,
         'prev_text' => __('<i class="fa-regular fa-angle-left"></i><span>Indietro</span>'), 
         'next_text' => __('<span>Avanti</span><i class="fa-regular fa-angle-right"></i>'),
         'type'          => 'plain',
         'add_args'      => false,
         'add_fragment'  => ''
        ); 
    echo paginate_links($args);   
}       

else {
    ?><div class="msg_orders">La tua cronologia ordini è vuota!</div><?php
} 

?></div><?php
    

?>
</div>
```

Comment: Stop posting same question. I explained to you where is the problem u didnt even bother to debug it,.

Comment: @MartinMirchev Sorry, and that I updated the question by modifying the code for this I made a new one, I have specified the problem better. Anyway you told me not to define total, but if I don't, nothing works. Thank you for the suggestions and your time, I appreciate it.

If you like, could you give a clearer example of what you mean? Also now I'm not using numberposts.

Comment: I don't see you using the value of `$current_page` anywhere in your data selection.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for the comment, I defined `$current_page` like this `$current_page = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;` to insert the variable in the code for pagination. How else was I supposed to use it?

Comment: You are supposed to _also_ use it in your query, that fetches the data. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#pagination-parameters

Comment: @CBroe In my query `$customer_orders` I have now added `'paged'  => $current_page,` but the problem persists. I get all the real page numbers, but when I click to change page I always stay on the same page. To do this I moved `$customer_orders` a few lines above otherwise it would tell me undefined variable for `$current_page`.

Comment: Have you checked that the value of `$current_page` actually matches the page you are trying to navigate to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246368/discussion-between-snorlax-and-cbroe).

Comment: if I do var_dump($current_page); get this -> int(1)
From the reference you sent me it says the following: paged (int) – number of page. Show the posts that would normally show up just on page X when using the “Older Entries” link. This means that actually only the start page is loaded, I understand. Right ?

Also I have tried both `page` and `paged` but the problem persists.

Comment: @MartinMirchev I followed your hint and debugged `'total' => $customer_orders-> max_num_pages` but the problem persists. Do you have any other tips for me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took some time but, looking with a more relaxed mind, I was able to find the solution to the problem. I leave the solution below for anyone who needs it.

The first thing I did was read the wordpress reference on paginate_links: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/

Looking at the various examples available in the reference I understood that something was wrong with the `$current_page = ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;`. I was probably applying it badly. I did various tests following the reference but was unsuccessful, so I went to search for other posts here on stackoverflow to better understand how the $paged variable is used (which in my case I called $current_page).

After my research I found this post that led me to the final solution: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/275527/paginate-links-ignore-my-format

This helped me since it actually pagination was ignoring my links because when I clicked there it didn’t redirect, but refresh the current page every time.

**This is what I did to solve the problem**:

1. I changed `$current_page = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;` to `$current_page = max( 1, (int) filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'pagina' ) );`
2. Then I also changed the format value in the pagination array `'format' => '?pagina=%#%',`

Note that 'pagina' has been filtered to `filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'pagina')` otherwise the pagination will not work.

**This is what my custom endpoint template looks like**

```
<?php

?><div class="orders-container"><?php


defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

$downloads     = WC()->customer->get_downloadable_products();
$has_downloads = (bool) $downloads;


do_action( 'woocommerce_before_account_downloads', $has_downloads );

if ( $has_downloads ) {
                
 ?><table class="table_orders heading"><tr>
  <td class="product_number">Ordine</td>
  <td class="product_name">Prodotto</td>
  <td class="product_data">Data</td>
  <td class="product_price">Totale</td>
  <td class="product_status">Stato</td>
   <td class="product_action">File</td>
 </tr></table><?php
   
    
    $order_statuses = array('wc-completed');
    $paged = max( 1, (int) filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'pagina' ) );

    $args = apply_filters('woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query',array(
    'customer_id'     => get_current_user_id(),
    'post_status'     => $order_statuses,
    'paged'           => $paged,
    'posts_per_page'  => 3,
    'paginate'        => true,
    ));
    $customer_orders = wc_get_orders( $args );

    // Get Access $order variable Foreach - Definisci le variabili sotto per poi utilizzarle in echo
    foreach($customer_orders->orders as $order) {
     // Get $product object from $order / $order_id
     $orders_id = $order->get_id();
     $status =  wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() );
     $date_created = $order->get_date_created()->date('d/m/Y');
     $payment_method = $order->get_payment_method_title();
     $order_total = $order->get_formatted_order_total();

        // Get Access Items & Product Variable Foreach
        foreach($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item) {
         $product_name = $item->get_name();
         $view_order = $order->get_view_order_url();

         // Get product image - https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-product-info-title-sku-desc-product-object/
         $product = $item->get_product();
            if( $product instanceof WC_Product ){
             $order_img = $product->get_image();
            }
    
         //Get product download button 
         $downloads = $order->get_downloadable_items();
            if(is_array($downloads)) {
                foreach($downloads as $product){
                 $download_button = '<a href="'. $product['download_url'] .'" target="_blank">Download</a>';
                } 
            } 

            echo '
                <table class="table_orders">
                <tr class="table_row_items">
                    <td class="product_number">
                     <span class="mobile title">Ordine</span>
                     <span>#'. esc_attr($orders_id) .'</span>
                    </td>
    
                    <td class="product_name">
                     <span class="mobile title">Prodotto</span>
                     <a href="'. wp_kses_post($view_order) .'">'. wp_kses_post($product_name) .'</a>
                    </td>
    
                    <td class="product_data">
                     <span class="mobile title">Data</span>
                     <span>'. wp_kses_post($date_created) .'</span>
                    </td>
    
                    <td class="product_price">
                     <span class="mobile title">Prezzo</span>
                     <span>'. wp_kses_post($order_total) .'</span>
                    </td>
    
                    <td class="product_status">
                     <span class="mobile title">Stato</span>
                     <span class="label ' . $order->get_status() . '">'. wp_kses_post($status) .'</span>
                    </td>
 
                    <td class="product_action">
                     <span class="mobile title">File</span>
                     <a target=”_blank” href="'. esc_url($view_order) .'">Visualizza<i class="fa-duotone fa-eye"></i></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>    
                </table> 
            ';

            // Tasto download funzionante - if($downloads) { echo '<div class="container_orders_download"> '. $download_button .' </div>'; }
        }
    }


    // Pagination button - Responsabile dei bottoni e numerazione delle pagine della cronologia ordini
    ?><div class="container-pagination"><?php 
        $args = array(
         'base'          => esc_url( wc_get_endpoint_url( 'libreria') ) . '%_%',
         'format'        => '?pagina=%#%',
         'total'         => $customer_orders->max_num_pages,
         'current'       => $paged,
         'show_all'      => false,
         'end_size'      => 3,
         'mid_size'      => 3,
         'prev_next'     => true,
         'prev_text' => __('<i class="fa-regular fa-angle-left"></i><span>Indietro</span>'), 
         'next_text' => __('<span>Avanti</span><i class="fa-regular fa-angle-right"></i>'),
         'type'          => 'plain',
         'add_args'      => false,
         'add_fragment'  => ''
        ); 
    echo paginate_links($args);   
}       
        else {
         ?><div class="msg_orders">La tua cronologia ordini è vuota!</div><?php
        } 
    ?></div><?php
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_account_downloads', $has_downloads );

?>
</div>
```